# how can I paginate data in Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, spring-rest

I used CassandraRepository, but I couldn't paginate my data.

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountDaoInter extends CassandraRepository<Account,String> {
}
```

There is a method `findAll(Pageable pageable);` in CassandraRepository. (return type Slice<>)

I use CassandraPageRequest to create Pageable.

Service :

```
@Override
public List<AccountDTO> findAll(Integer page){
    Slice<Account> accounts = accountDaoInter.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.of(page,10));

    return accounts
            .stream()
            .map(account -> modelMapper.map(account,AccountDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Controller :

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<AccountDTO>> findAll(@RequestParam(name = "page") Integer p){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(accountServiceInter.findAll(--p));
}
```

When the page value is 1, result is okay.

When the page value is 2 and higher, I get Internal Server Error.

Error:

**`"Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0)."`**

[image: Error picture]

[Project](https://github.com/hamidsultanzadeh/microservices-course)

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not support fetching a random page, because of that Spring Data throws `InvalidArgumentException`. You should fetch the first page and then iterate until you get to the requested page. You can find more information about it and the rationale behind this behavior at Java driver docs on paging ([link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/paging/#offset-queries)).